# Angular-Cli Firebase Hosting: How to accept a query string from external server

Tags: angular, firebase, http-headers

location.href this gets the submitted url that I can then record, this works browser side ie . https://xxxx.firebaseapp.com/?page=123

However if I query it from an external source i.e a php script on another server `<?php get_content('https://xxxx.firebaseapp.com/?page=abcde'); ?>`  this does not seem to work.

Angular code...

```
    import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';


  constructor(
    public location: Location
  ) {
var url =  window.location.href
....//save the info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use firebase functions to do this here is a link to the tutorial,.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started.

So if I were to make a new folder and do a

```
npm i -g firbase-tools;
firebase init;
```

then setup using firbase init selecting the correct project "functions" as a selection (for your actual project you may need to select multiple options)

you then navigate into the functions folder `/myproject/functions/index.js`

This is some code I use that uses the instructions above to save data to the firebase DB.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
// Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const data = req.query;
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  return admin.database().ref('/paymentslog').push({data}).then((snapshot) => {
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    return res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
  });
});
```

So data is pushed to `/paymentslog` in the Firebase DB... the way my code is setup is that EVERYTHING in the query string is added dynamicaly

So if you were using PHP (`file_get_contents`) or AngularCli (`http.post`) running some where else you would simple use post http header to your url using quersthings like `https://us-central1-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/addMessage?id=9955&&price=123&foo=hello`

will save as

```
/paymentslog/randomkey/id = 9955
/paymentslog/randomkey/price = 123
/paymentslog/randomkey/foo = hello
```

The "randomkey" comes from the fact I am using .push

I could do `ref('/paymentslog/' + id).set` instead to create

```
/paymentslog/9955/price = 123
/paymentslog/9955/foo = hello
```

When you are ready to test this you can do a `firebase deploy` that will upload the code to your project

I should mention that you do not need the API credentials because the firebase init sets them up for you.

For your AngularCLI project this is some example code for getting http.post working

```
private form_send_url:string = 'https://us-central1-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/addMessage';

this._http.post(
  this.form_send_url,
  {
    'id':encodeURI("9955"),
    'price':encodeURI("123"),
    'foo':encodeURI("hello")
  },
  {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
).then(data => {
  console.log(data.status);
  console.log(data.data); // data received by server
  console.log(data.headers);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error.status);
  console.log(error.error); // error message as string
  console.log(error.headers);
}).then(() => {
  this._navCtrl.push(goto new page);
});

});
```