# How to do Query String in Firebase Hosting?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to send userID from client to firebase on Query String.
I confirmed that I can set Query String on firebase Hosting URL.
But I don't know how to read Query String from React source.

How to do Query String in Firebase Hosting?

edit:2018/08/27 Add Detail

I use firebase Hostings, Storage, Database.
Now, I want to know client's userID from Hosting.
The reason why I don't want to use Database is that users who are now acsessing that userID can not be obtained directly from Hosting are not associated with user IDs. 
So, I thought that I send client's userID to Hostingon Query String.

Comment: My answer here is what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334500/angular-cli-firebase-hosting-how-to-accept-a-query-string-from-external-server/51963297#51963297

Comment: I checked your answer and I tried. I could userID in fuctions. But I want to know client's userID from Hosted React Source. Can I do this??

Comment: Lets say that you have a query-sting with your projects id in https://us-central1-MY_PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/addMessage?=userID=123456 if you copy my exact code into a firebase function and then do this querystring it should write the data to the database you can then do something with it. It does not matter if its React or any other code like PHP, its a querystring HTTP Header that is passing the data

Comment: Please update your question with additional details about what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I added. I am pleased if details are conveyed.